# Неправильная сортировка событий во временной шкале

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, временная-шкала

[Во временной шкале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/602729/timeline) события начинаются с итогов голосования, а по логике первым событием должно быть создание вопроса/ответа, т.е. дата ежедневного подсчета голосов в 00:00:00 отображается не по порядку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иными словами, по логике, дата подсчета голосов в 00:00:00 должна отображатся в конце суток, а не в начале.

Comment: Сортировка правильная. Не правильная сама дата.

Comment: @alexolut а какая дата должна быть? 24:00:00 даты нет

Comment: Посмотрите мой [комментарий](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271996/timeline-vote-summary-shows-votes-for-the-24-hours-following-the-timestamp-whic#comment935023_271996) на англоМете к аналогичному вопросу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из отображения ежедневного отчёта по голосам убираю время вообще. Это отчёт за весь день, так что время там не нужно.

Также в сортировке он теперь приходится на конец дня, т. к. покрывает весь день.

Будет в следующей сборке.

---

I am removing the time portion altogether from the display of the daily summary of votes. As a summary of a day, it shouldn't have a time portion at all.

Additionally, I sorted it to the end of the day, given it covers the whole day.

With you in the next build.